# How to update values in a current table with a return value from a dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the results of my query into an existing table, as you can see it's a dynamic query and I don't know how to insert the update function in this code. When I insert it into the while function it sendS QUERY EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY but there isn't any update..

**I used this code for the dynamic query:**

```
                    Declare @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
                    DECLARE @TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(max);
                    DECLARE @COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR(max);
                    DECLARE @COUNTER INT;
                    SET @TABLENAME = 'MOMENTUM_Results';
                    SET @COUNTER = 2;

                    WHILE @COUNTER<=122
                    BEGIN

                        SELECT @COLUMN1 = C.Name
                        FROM sys.Columns C
                         WHERE OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = @TABLENAME 
                         AND C.column_id = @COUNTER
                          ;



                           SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.[' + @COLUMN1 + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
                             Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @COLUMN1 + '] = 5'



                            EXECUTE (@SQL)



                              SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;

                        END
```

**To obtain these results:**

[image]

**And now I want to update a current table by using this code:**

```
                   UPDATE MOMENTUM_Results

                   SET @COLUMN1 = @SQL

                   WHERE [MNEMONIC]='RANK_5';
```

The problem is I don't know where to place it in the 1st code.. or how to properly use it.. and finally here is the **final format of the existing table** (final result I want to obtain, in which I want to insert the query results in the row RANK_5)

[image]

Does someone have any clue?

**PRINT RESULT:**

```
             DECLARE @avg as float;

             SELECT @avg = AVG(MR.[2006-12-30]) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 

             Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[2006-12-30] = 5;

            UPDATE MOMENTUM_Results_new  SET  @COLUMN1 = @avg
             WHERE [MNEMONIC]=RANK_5
```

**EXECUTE RESULT:**

```
               Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
               Must declare the scalar variable "@COLUMN1".
               Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
               Must declare the scalar variable "@COLUMN1".
               Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
               Must declare the scalar variable "@COLUMN1".
               Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
               Must declare the scalar variable "@COLUMN1".
               Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
               Must declare the scalar variable "@COLUMN1".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SQL is just a string, not the SELECT result of your dynamic query, so executing SET @COLUMN1 = @SQL is not probably what you want. Also when you execute dynamic sql you should consider the dynamic query and the rest of your code as two "parallel universes", the only thing that connects them is the common tables they may be editing. I would advise you declare a variable inside the dynamic query, assign to it the result of your AVG function and execute UPDATE in the dynamic too. Something like this:

```
                Declare @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
                DECLARE @TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(max);
                DECLARE @COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR(max);
                DECLARE @COUNTER INT;
                SET @TABLENAME = 'MOMENTUM_Results';
                SET @COUNTER = 2;

                WHILE @COUNTER<=122
                BEGIN

                    SELECT @COLUMN1 = C.Name
                    FROM sys.Columns C
                     WHERE OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = @TABLENAME 
                     AND C.column_id = @COUNTER
                      ;

                SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @avg float; 
                        SELECT @avg = AVG(MR.[' + @COLUMN1 + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
                         Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @COLUMN1 + '] = 5;
                        UPDATE '+@TABLENAME+' SET ' + @COLUMN1 + '= @avg
                        WHERE [MNEMONIC]=''RANK_5'''

               EXECUTE (@SQL)



                      SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;

                END
```

I may have syntax errors, I haven't tested it but you see my point

Comment: it's weird bc I declare the variable @avg and I get this error message: "Must declare the scalar variable "@avg""

Comment: @Robin_Hcp I am confused because the answer was accepted. Have you declared the variable inside the dynamic query? Because if you did it outside as normal code, the query can't detect it, because the query is executed in a different session

Comment: I got it! but it didn't update the table, the table keeps showing NULL values in the row RANK_5

Comment: You can call PRINT @SQL just before EXEC to see that the dynamic query was constructed properly and mistake has been made

Comment: I edited my question with the results of the PRINT  and EXECUTE, so you can better understand what's going on

Comment: @Robin_Hcp the UPDATE command is totally missing from the dynamic query. Are you sure you constructed the right way? I updated my answer, containing your whole code in it , in order to make it more understandable. Make sure your quotation marks are placed properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137033/discussion-between-jambonick-and-robin-hcp).

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement only updates a variable.
SET @xyz = @abc will set the @xyz variable.

Try this:

```
UPDATE MOMENTUM_Results
SET COLUMN1 = @SQL
WHERE [MNEMONIC]='RANK_5';
```

(Note: I didn't see a "Column1" in your screenshot so I don't know if that column exists in your MOMENTUM_Results table. I might also be misunderstanding your question... are you wanting to update values in the MOMENTUM_Results table with a return value from the dynamic query? That's a different answer.

-EDIT-

Try changing your dynamic SQL to use "UPDATE ..." instead of "SELECT"

Something like

```
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE MOMENTUM_Results SET ' + @COLUMN1 + ' = AVG(MR.[' + @COLUMN1 + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
                             Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @COLUMN1 + '] = 5 AND MOMENTUM_Results.MNEMONIC=''RANK_5'''
```

Comment: If it's the latter, which it feels like - try changing your dynamic SQL to use "UPDATE ..." instead of "SELECT"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's exactly what you said, I am trying to update values in the MOMENTUM_Results table with a return value from the dynamic query!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to build a single sql kind of

```
UPDATE mrs SET
 col1 = x.co1, col2 = x.col2, ..
FROM MOMENTUM_Results mrs 
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT AVG(case mq.col1 when 5 then mr.col1 end) col1, ..
 FROM MOMENTUM_Quintile mq 
 LEFT JOIN MOMENTUM_Returns mr ON MQ.Mnemonic = mr.Mnemonic 
                     AND (5 IN mq.col1, ..)
) x
WHERE mrs.[MNEMONIC]='RANK_5';
```

where col1, col2 .. are set dynamically.